# Importing data from .xls files when gettimg data from a folder in power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

I have tried to get data from a particular folder containing only .xls using power query without any luck. Right now I'm running a macro to save as .xlsx before refreshing the data, however, I'd like to reduce that step and get data without having to change the format.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: https://sqlitybi.com/loading-multiple-excel-files-from-a-folder-in-power-bi/

Comment: It doesn't say specifically about .xls

Comment: Did you try this solution? It should be similar to other extension (csv/xls/xlsx )

Comment: I have no issues importing .xls files.  What exactly is your issue?  Does the query fail?  Spit out an error message?